# Javascript onclick ontouch

Tags: javascript

I want to offer very limited drawing possibilities in a html canvas, on any device. Only three things can happen when the user interacts : a "unit" (it might be 40px for example, or 10, it is not very important) square appears where there was none, a rectangle disappears when "clicked", and lastly, several rectangles are fused.

The first two need a click to be detected (same down and up coordinates), the latter needs a drag to be detected (different down and up coordinates).

Therefore, the only thing the app needs to do is to detect (and remember) down, then up coordinates, whether it is a touch, a click, or anything at all.

Lastly, I do not wish to use jquery or any lib, but rather learn something from my coding.

Does this code look ok for that purpose? Can you propose ameliorations?

```
canvas.ontouchstart = canvas.onmousedown = onDown;
function onDown(e) {
  saveDownCoords(e);
  e.preventDefault();
};
canvas.ontouchend = canvas.onmouseup = onUp;
function onUp(e) {
  ...do whatever;
};
```

Second question, about preventDefault(), stopPropagation() (or whatever it is called): I have read it was needed to stop events from registering twice, as touches and clicks - but under which circumstances and devices, exactly, do touch events then click events fire for a unique user physical action?

Comment: I'm ok to have a question closed, but it would be better with a comment explaining why, I could maybe reword it if I knew what tickled your fancy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For your first question, it's better to use `element.addEventListener()` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

```
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // If you need to
    // ... Do whatever
}
```

As for your second question, the `event.preventDefault()` call is there to stop the default behavior. It could be used to prevent double-clicking from selecting text, for example.

Comment: As for my 2nd question, it's really more about touch then click. Under which circumstances does a touch THEN a click fire from one physical user action?

Comment: The `touch` events are different from the mouse or keyboard ones, and are not supported by IE / Edge : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events Using `preventDefault` could, although I am not sure about that one, prevent scrolling, if the user started touching the screen *inside* the canvas

Comment: Since your syntax is the newer syntax, I will use it. Is it actually better for a "real" reason, not for a js version reason? Also my question is really about the "algorithm", not the syntax. Is there a better way to capture ontouchdown ontouchup on mousedown onmouseup, or is that just about the minimum failsafe code to do it (I can't believe no one ever pondered the very same thing and came to answer :p)

Comment: The syntax I used is better as you can attach multiple listeners, whereas with yours, you change the listener's reference, "disabling" the previous one. Using `addEventListener` or your method is indeed the only way (that I know of) for getting the user's inputs. I can guarantee you that to this day, you cannot "fetch" the current input's state, would it be keyboard, mouse or touchscreen